# Reduce the line of code in XML file by defining variables

Tags: xml, ant

Below is the XML file i'm having currently.

```
<target name="created-date-US" depends="CopyConfig">
    <runTestNG xmlConfigFile="ddbTest.xml" domain="test" realm="US" locale="USD"/>
</target>

<target name="created-date-EU" depends="CopyConfig">
    <runTestNG xmlConfigFile="ddbTest.xml" domain="test" realm="EU" locale="EUR"/>
</target>

<target name="created-date-JP" depends="CopyConfig">
    <runTestNG xmlConfigFile="ddbTest.xml" domain="test" realm="JP" locale="JPY"/>
</target>
```

As i'm new in programming domain, so i'm looking is there any way through which i can reduce the length of the above xml file to something like below ?

```
<target name="created-date-{region}" depends="CopyConfig">
    <runTestNG xmlConfigFile="ddbTest.xml" domain="test" realm="{realm}" locale="{locale}"/>
</target>
```

Thanks for the help in advance, and apologies if the question framing sentence is not correct :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this at the XML level, but this looks like an Ant file, and you can certainly do it at the Ant level. Something along the lines

```
<property name="realm" value="US"/>
<target name="created-date-${realm}" depends="CopyConfig">
    <runTestNG xmlConfigFile="ddbTest.xml" domain="test" realm="${realm}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: How i can able to add EU and FE ? According to the way suggested it seems that i need to write 3 lines still. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: You can create an Ant macro and then invoke it with different values of parameters. But I'm no Ant expert. The key thing is that you need to be looking in Ant documentation for this, it's not done at XML level.